# Nine Patch images and libraries

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have an Android Library with some nine-patch images (.9.png). I have also two projects that use the library.

The problem is that in one project I see all the nine path correctly and in the other one I see the border lines and the images are not expanded.

Both projects have similar AndroidManifest.XML files and both are compiled with Android 2.3.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to delete bin and gen folders and clean the project with no success.

The only way to solve this is to create a new project and then copy the source code into the new project.

Comment: I get the same problem at times, have to do the same thing.